# How to trigger Function in Function at Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
    getData (date) {
      console.log(‘Executed!!’)
      Promise.resolve()
        .then(() => this.$store.commit('Loading/show'))
        .then(() => this.getShopList())
        .then(() => Promise.all([
          axios.get(`/shop/v2/${this.selectedShopId}`),
          axios.get(`/shop/${this.selectedShopId}/businessStatus`),
          axios.get(`/shop/${this.selectedShopId}/schedule`, { params: { targetDate: date.toISOString(true) } }),
          axios.get(`/shop/${this.selectedShopId}/floormap_image`),
          axios.get('/shop/room/keep')
        ]))
        .then(res => {
          this.shopInfo = res[0].data
          this.info = res[1].data
          this.schedule = res[2].data
          this.url_floormap_image = res[3].data
          this.keepList = res[4].data
          )
        })
        .catch(ex => { this.error(ex) })
        .finally(() => this.$store.commit('Loading/hide'))
    },
```

The code above
It is called in the code below.

```
    updateMemoChecklist (memoText) {
      return Promise.resolve()
        .then(() => this.$store.commit('Loading/show'))
        .then(() => {
          const promises = this.checkedItems.map(item => {
            const { shopId, roomId, keepRoomId, lastUpdateAt, startDate, endDate } = item
            const req = {
              startDate: startDate,
              endDate: endDate,
              memo: memoText,
              lastUpdateAt: lastUpdateAt
            }
            return axios.patch(`/shop/${shopId}/rooms/${roomId}/keep/${keepRoomId}`, req)
          })
          return Promise.all(promises)
        })
        .then(() => {
          this.$emit('input', false)
          this.$emit('change')
          return this.getData(this.selectedDate) // I call it here!!
        })
        .then(() => {
          this.isOpenRegisterComplete = true
        })
        .then(() => {
          console.log(‘Updated Data’, this.shopInfo, this.info, this.schedule, this.url_floormap_image, this.keepList)
          })
        })
        .catch((ex) => {
          this.error(ex)
        })
        .finally(() => this.$store.commit('Loading/hide'))
    },
```

At ↑
I think that this.getData(this.selectedDate) should be executed in “updateMemoChecklist ” but
console.log('Updated data', this.shopInfo, this.info, this.schedule, this.url_floormap_image, this.keepList) is not updated.
(When I reload screen, it has been updated)
I have confirmed that this.getData(this.selectedDate) is executed properly because I can see “console.log(‘Executed!!’)”.

console.log(‘Updated Data’, this.shopInfo, this.info, this.schedule, this.url_floormap_image, this.keepList)

should be updated.

Comment: Can you clarify what does "is not updated" mean? Is console.log called with wrong values or not called at all?

Answer (score 0):

Finally this one works!

```
updateMemoChecklist (memoText) {
  return Promise.resolve()
    .then(() => this.$store.commit('Loading/show'))
    .then(() => {
      const promises = this.checkedItems.map(item => {
        const { shopId, roomId, keepRoomId, lastUpdateAt, startDate, endDate } = item
        const req = {
          startDate: startDate,
          endDate: endDate,
          memo: memoText,
          lastUpdateAt: lastUpdateAt
        }
        return axios.patch(`/shop/${shopId}/rooms/${roomId}/keep/${keepRoomId}`, req)
      })
      return Promise.all(promises)
    })
    .then(() => {
      this.$emit('input', false)
      this.$emit('change')
      return this.getData(this.selectedDate)
    })
    .then(() => {
      this.isOpenRegisterComplete = true
    })
    .then(() => {
      this.checkedItems.forEach(item => {
        const foundItem = this.keepList.find(keepItem => keepItem.keepRoomId === item.keepRoomId)
        if (foundItem) {
          item.lastUpdateAt = foundItem.lastUpdateAt
        }
      })
    })
    .catch((ex) => {
      this.error(ex)
    })
    .finally(() => this.$store.commit('Loading/hide'))
},
```